# React Router - Navigating direct to route returns 404

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I will draw the whole picture of the app, how my router looks like:

index.tsx

```js
render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.tsx

```js
const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
      <MainLayout title='Home'>
            <Routes location={location}>
              {routes.map(({ path, Component }) => (
                <Route
                  key={path}
                  path={path}
                  element={<Component />}
                />
              ))}
            </Routes>
      </MainLayout>
  );
};
```

I have defined routes in a separate object and the route type looks like this:

```js
export type Route = Readonly<{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    path: string;
    Component: RouteComponent;
    params?: Readonly<Params<string>>;
}>;
```

Route objects looks like this:

```js
export const Routes: Route[] = [
    {
        id: 0,
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        Component: Homepage
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        Component: About
    },
]
```

And I am using `react-router": "^6.2.1"`

I have more routes, but I simplified the problem because the logic is the same.

The problem is that on dev mode, when I run it locally, I can navigate direct to `localhost:3000/about` or `localhost:3000/categories/3/articles/23` and it will return the article 23 under categories with id 3, but i deployed using azure static sites and it **doesn't find the route**.
If I navigate to `/` home route, and then `/about` it is fine, also going back. But navigating direct to a route returns 404.
[image]

Comment: You will need to make sure you serve the `index.html` file no matter what route is requested. Never used azure, but the problem lies there. You need to configure it properly.

Comment: Thanks man, life saving. After googling around based on your comment, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659777/serving-index-html-on-all-the-incoming-http-requests-in-node-js) solution.

Comment: There is another answer doesn't require server side adjusting. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71863634/react-route-404-not-found-after-refreshing-the-deployed-application/71863865#71863865